# boolean evaluation of Object optional property that can be NaN?

Tags: javascript, object, nan

The following is a normal property check in JS:

```
if (x.prop && Array.isArray(x.prop) ) ...
```

Where the short-cut evaluation results in x.prop === undefined, and the expression evaluates as false. But:

```
var o = {a: NaN};
if (o.a && isNaN(o.a)) ...
```

Results in the coercion of `(NaN && true)` -> `(NaN)` -> `(false)`, so the condition of having property `'a'` and it being `NaN` is never evaluated to true.

It seems that I cannot check NaN-able properties as I would most other properties. Have I been "doing it wrong" all this time, or should I have always used `o.hasOwnProperty()`? Or `typeof (o.prop) === 'undefined'`? Or is this just a JS quirk where the two conditions are both valid but cannot be combined because it's JS.

What is the "best practice"? (And why?) By best, I'd prioritize  correctness, readability and speed (in that order).

Comment: You can use `("a" in o)` to see whether there's a property called "a" with *any* value (including `undefined`).

Comment: Oh, that's news to me! Thanks!

Comment: Why would you not just use `if (Array.isArray(x.prop))`?

Answer (score 0):

You could omit the check for the property and check the object itself and then the property.

```js
var o;
console.log(o && isNaN(o.a));

o = {};
console.log(o && isNaN(o.a));

o = { a: NaN };
console.log(o && isNaN(o.a));
```

Comment: One of the problems I see with this is that the middle case will return `true` despite `a` not existing.  This can cause problems if you evaluate this expression and expect `a` to exist so that you can perform manipulation on it.

Comment: @MarcusParsons, it depends on the use cases. op has not stated, what is exactly to test.

Comment: I, like many others, would not test for `isNaN` unless I expected `a` to be an existing property.

Answer (score 0):

When the compiler is evaulating `o.a`, it supplements `o.a` for its value which is `NaN` which is a falsey value.  Since there is no boolean comparison for this falsey value, the compiler evaluates it and returns a false.

To mitigate this from occurring, you can use `typeof` to make sure that it is not `undefined`.  I would do this check first to make sure that it exists, and then evaluate it to see if it is `NaN`.

```
var o = { a: NaN };

//outputs a is NaN
if (typeof o.a !== "undefined") {
    if (isNaN(o.a)) {
        console.log("a is NaN");
    }
}
```